# RCT Multiple regression: should I include the control group in the model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

If I have an experimental group and a control group in a RCT; and I am trying to estimate the intervention effect on the dependent variables of the participants under control of several covariates using a multiple regression model (instructions, not by choice), should I include all cases from both treatment and control groups in the model?

Comment: how would you estimate the intervention effect *without* the controls?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Makes sense. However, how should I go about this? Should I do interactions? Or should I run the regression with the grouping variable only, then start adding the covariates one by one?

Comment: usually you would estimate a treatment effect by comparing the final outcome between the treated and control units, while controlling for the covariates (so long as the covariates were measured before the randomisation or at the very least before the intervention).

Comment: @GeorgeSavva  So I should split the data into two groups (treatment and control), then build a multiple regression model for each group, then compare?

Comment: No, you make a single model with all of the data. It's impossible to explain all this as a single question, respectfully I suggest you do some reading around RCT analysis.